# This is not a JSON Array. (retrofit, gson)

Tags: arrays, json, gson, retrofit

It is retrofit code

```
Retrofit builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(APIUrl.API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RestAPI restAPI = builder.create(RestAPI.class);
    Call<JsonObject> call = restAPI.wiseSaying();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
            Log.d("response----", response.body().toString());

            JsonArray jsonArray = response.body().getAsJsonArray();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

---

```
{"phrase":"[{\"author\":\"abc\",\"say\":\"aaaaa\"},
{\"author\":\"def\",\"say\":\"sdffdf.\"},
{\"author\":\"gsdf\",\"say\":\"dsfdsfdsf.\"}]"}
```

It's response.(Log result) I think JsonArray
But error ㅠ_ㅠ

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.dsm.wakeheart, PID: 28267
                                                               java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.
                                                                   at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonArray(JsonElement.java:106)
                                                                   at com.dsm.wakeheart.Fragment.WiseSayingFragment$1.onResponse(WiseSayingFragment.java:82)
                                                                   at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I was using jsonprimitive instead of jsonarray, so I did not get an error. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are trying to save the JsonObject to a JsonArray . Try to save it to a JsonObject variable.

```
JSONObject jsonObject= response.body();
try {
JSONArray jsonAr=jsonObject.getJSONArray("phrase");
} 
catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```